# WebRtcAudioRecord.context is leaking reported by leak canary. How to solve?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, webrtc, leakcanary

My webrtc Android native application has issue with `WebRtcAudioRecord.context`. Leak canary is continuously reporting that `WebRtcAudioRecord.class` is leaking memory.

I do dispose my webrtc components this way:

```
 peerConnection?.dispose()
 videoCapture?.dispose()
 videoSource?.dispose()
 factory.dispose()
 PeerConnectionFactory.stopInternalTracingCapture()
 PeerConnectionFactory.shutdownInternalTracer()
```

But Leak canary still keep reporting that `WebRtcAudioRecord.context` is leaking.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

My application doesn't stream audio is only streaming video.

This is the canary memory leak report:

> ┬─── │ GC Root: Global variable in native code │ ├─
> org.webrtc.audio.WebRtcAudioRecord instance │    Leaking: UNKNOWN │
> Retaining 99 B in 2 objects │    context instance of .ui.activities. │
> MainActivity with mDestroyed = true │    ↓ WebRtcAudioRecord.context │
>
> ╰→ .ui.activities.MainActivity instance ​     Leaking: YES
> (ObjectWatcher was watching this because .ui.activities.MainActivity
> received Activity#onDestroy() ​     callback and Activity#mDestroyed
> is true) ​     Retaining 153.0 kB in 2750 objects ​     key =
> 33e94f80-0004-4aeb-b351-dab64a8280da ​     watchDurationMillis = 5134
> ​     retainedDurationMillis = 134 ​     mApplication instance of .App
> ​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>
> METADATA
>
> Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29 Build.MANUFACTURER: HUAWEI LeakCanary
> version: 2.6 App process name: some.app Count of retained yet cleared:
> 10 KeyedWeakReference instances Stats:
> LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=4250,misses=80514,hitRate=5%]
> RandomAccess[bytes=4071605,reads=80514,travel=36763422162,range=23400016,size=29
> 171709] Heap dump reason: 8 retained objects, app is visible Analysis
> duration: 4019 ms

[image]

Comment: The leaktrace you pasted looks partial and badly formatted. Can you update with a properly formatted and full leaktrace?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesRicau I just updated screenshot to see originally formatted and full leaktraced directly from LeakCanary

Comment: You'll need to figure out what code is creating WebRtcAudioRecord instances and make sure you pass it the Application instance instead of Activity instance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason!

For me,it was

```
 val options = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
            .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
            .setFieldTrials("WebRTC-H264HighProfile/Enabled/")
            .createInitializationOptions()
```

I was passing the activity context instead of application context here for the builder.